# OpenOffice : добавить еще одно значение в формуле суммы по условиям

Tags: open-office

Есть формула, которая делает подсчет в зависимости от того что в столбцах.

```
=SUMIFS(F13:F200;H13:H200;"DONE";H13:H200;"<>CLOSED";G13:G200;"MERCEDES"
```

Меня интересует последнее значение JOE, к примеру что нужно внести в формулу, чтобы подсчитывало если в стобце **MERCEDES**, **BMW**, **LADA**.

Так как в данном случае подсчитывает только **MERCEDES**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
H13:H200;"DONE";H13:H200;"<>CLOSED"
```

Второе условие истинно, если значение любое, кроме *CLOSED*. Первое условие говорит о том, что *ИСТИНА* только при одном значении. Вывод: вторая проверка лишняя.

В *Excel* можно работать с массивами констант:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(F13:F200;H13:H200;"DONE";G13:G200;{"MERCEDES";"BMW";"LADA"}))
```

Если в *OpenOffice* такое не сработает, записать суму трех одинаковых функций с разными искомыми текстами:

```
=SUMIFS(F13:F200;H13:H200;"DONE";G13:G200;"MERCEDES")+SUMIFS(F13:F200;H13:H200;"DONE";G13:G200;"BMW")+SUMIFS(F13:F200;H13:H200;"DONE";G13:G200;"LADA")
```

Comment: первая формула работает, но считает только 1 значение из массива.. MERCEDES, с второй формулой не понял что нужно сделать ? можете привести пример как в первой ?

Comment: Записал вторую формулу полностью. По первой: значит, *OpenOffice* не принимает массивы констант

Comment: Отлично ! последняя формула работает !

Comment: Вопрос номер два.. нужно подсчитать не 
 сумму, а кол-во стобцов с значениями, делаю так, =COUNTIF(G13:G200;"MERCEDES";) работает, но как добавить второй вариант, чтобы считалось только там где H будет DONE

Comment: Сестричку используйте - *COUNTIFS*