# Суммировать в зависимости от 3 значений - Openoffice

Tags: open-office

Есть четыре столбца

> A B C D

Столбец **D** содержит числа.

Как создать формулу: если в столбце **A** находим **HELLO**, в столбце **B** находим **BYE**, в столбце **C** находим **YES**, то суммировать то, что в столбце **D**

Т.е. нужно проверить сразу три условия, по которым будет производится суммирование.

Comment: Вопросы немного разные, но учитывая то, что автор у них один и функция одинакова - дубль https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839763/openoffice-добавить-еще-одно-значение-в-формуле-суммы-по-условиям

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [OpenOffice : добавить еще одно значение в формуле суммы по условиям](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839763/openoffice-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc)

Comment: Думаю вопрос не одинаковый, так как суммировать нужно по 3 значениям один столбик, а он кажется считает по 2 раза (если использовать +SUMIFS) т.е у меня 3 значения идут в ряд, вот если эти три значения совпадают с условием, тогда нужно это вносить в общую сумму. В том примере что Вы указали, немного не так (там суммируется по двум разным условиям которые находятся в селекте) в этом случае они находятся в разных стобцах

Comment: Там данные столбца F суммируются по условиям столбцов H и G. СУММ используется только для суммирования по разным значениям G. Здесь это не нужно. Используйте SUMIFS, добавив условие по третьему столбцу

Comment: Запутался в ответе, можно пример ?

Comment: Странно почему, мне нотификация не пришла, только увидел.

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUMIFS(D2:D9;A2:A9;"HELLO";B2:B9;"BYE";C2:C9;"YES")
=СУММЕСЛИМН(D2:D9;A2:A9;"HELLO";B2:B9;"BYE";C2:C9;"YES")
```